# problem in importing the bioformats library

Tags: java, maven

I am new to the java programming language, I tried to use the bioformats library to read whole slide images for a project that I am working on but I keep getting the following problem:
"The import loci cannot be resolved"
You can find below the following code that I have tried using:

I am using maven for my project and running the code in vscode.

this is the Main.java file:

```java
package com.example;
import loci.formats.ImageReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IFormatReader reader = new ImageReader();
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

This is the XMl file (copy pasted from the maven central):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.opencb.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <relativePath>..</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>bioformats</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opencb.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lib</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.utgenome.thirdparty</groupId>
            <artifactId>picard</artifactId>
            <version>1.86p</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.2</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- TEST -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Maybe https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openmicroscopy/ome-common/6.0.21 and the like?

Comment: This is not a minimal reproducible example. Remove all dependencies that are not needed first.

Comment: @aled As I have previously state I am simply clueless about  Java . I just went to https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.opencb.commons/bioformats and copied the maven pom file. I have also tried using the first dependency close but to no avail.